# Django admin change error message ("Please correct the errors below.")

Tags: django, django-messages

Is it possible to change django admin error message.

i want add my custom error message.

**Please correct the errors below.** change this message

```
class mymodel(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # change message
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carefully reading [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations), we can see that we can override the base translations, as follows:

1. In your `settings.py`, add/update the following variable:

   ```
   LOCALE_PATHS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"locale"),
   ]
   ```
2. In your project's base directory, (where you find `manage.py`), create a folder named `locale` (or whatever, but if you rename it differently, change in step 1 as well).
3. In `locale` folder, create a folder for each language that you want to override. In our case, we want to override english, so we need to create a folder named `en`
4. In the `en` folder, create yet another folder, named `LC_MESSAGES`
5. In the `LC_MESSAGES` folder, create an empty **file** named `django.po`

At this point, this is what the contents of locale should look like

```
├── locale
│   └── en
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           └── django.po
```

6. Now we need to add in this `django.po` file whatever string we want to override from Django base translation. You can find them in the source code. For example, in your specific case, [this file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/contrib/admin/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po) tells us that the string id we need to override is on [line 459](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/contrib/admin/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po#L459):

   ```
   msgid "Please correct the errors below."
   ```
7. We use that id to provide a different string, so add the following to the `django.po` file:

   ```
   msgid "Please correct the errors below."
   msgstr "Fix the errors now!"
   ```

In this case, I took the original message and replaced it with `"Fix the errors now!"`

8. Recompile the messages with

   ```
   django-admin compilemessages
   ```

   This command should output should output a message like this:

   ```
   processing file django.po in /path/to/project/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
   ```
9. Django will now consider this file with higher priority and display the new message:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to solve this is by using translations, but that would require knowledge in editing `.PO` files and you will have to make a lot of changes to your code.

Fortunately, Django allows you to include extra `.css` files and `.js` files to a `ModelAdmin`.

The tricky idea is that you will create a javascript file in your `static` directory, and inside that file you will replace whatever text you wish

```
/static

    admin.js
```

## admin.js

```
// When the page is fully loaded

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    // Replace whatever text you wish, line by line
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('\\bPlease correct the errors below\\b', 'g'), 'Some fields are empty');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('\\bThis field is required\\b', 'g'), 'This field cannot be empty');
});
```

## admin.py

```
class mymodem(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ['admin.js']

    ....
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

[image]